# mapping request and returning modelAndView for the same file is allowed?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Here I have mapped request to `play.jsp` and returned the same file play as a ModelAndView. Is it allowed or not ?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/play.jsp")
public ModelAndView getQuestion(){
    List<Quiz> quiz= quizDaoImpl.getQuestion();
    return new ModelAndView("play", "quiz", quiz);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `allowed` ? What do you mean ? `compile`? `Function as expected` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I mean will this function return the play.jsp if I deploy /play.jsp in browser. And will the quiz list will be returned with play.jsp if it deploys

Comment: yes it is compiled without giving any error. But I am not getting the list of quiz in play.jsp so